# UINavigationBar moves my view

Tags: uiview, uinavigationbar, move, autoresize

I have a UINavigationBar that is hidden most of the time my app is running.

however when i was it to show i call

```
[navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
```

the view currently showing is resized..
 i then unchecked the "auto resize" option in interface builder.

now the view is moved down.

i there a way to load the navbar over the top of the view so it does move my view?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put your own navigationbar by picking from the Library.

use this code and put your navigation bar in the XIB of the view.

[navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];

Other wise your view will be come down by 44 points the height of the navigation bar.